# avg retorna nulo

Tags: mysql, mariadb

tengo una consulta que retorna el promedio de 2 columnas de tipo float, la cosa es que cambie la fecha de date a datetime para poder insertarla con la hora y ahora la consulta no funciona, me retorna nulo en ambas columnas

la tabla es:

```
create table mediciones(
    id int  not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    temperatura float not null,
    humedad float not null,
    idvinedo int not null,
    fecha datetime not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (idvinedo) REFERENCES vinedo(id));
```

y la consulta es:

```
SELECT AVG(temperatura) as temperatura, AVG(humedad) as humedad from
mediciones WHERE idvinedo=1 and fecha='2018-09-26'
```

la base de datos me da el siguiente mensaje cuando ejecuto la consulta:

> La selección actual no contiene una columna única.

espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

te devuelve Null, porque ahora es datetime y estás incluyendo sólamente la fecha como parte de a filtrar, si lo que realmente es obeneter la media indicando el día, independientemente de la hora, puedes modificar tu consulta:

```
    SELECT AVG(temperatura) as temperatura, AVG(humedad) as humedad from
mediciones WHERE idvinedo=1 and DATE(fecha)='2018-09-26';
```

Para el caso en que comentas

> La selección actual no contiene una columna única.

No he conseguido reproducirlo, la consulta es correcta.